# Event for a button in modal window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I am new to Javascript and was doing a simple website with a modal dialog. I face problems when invoking an event when clicking a button on the modal window:

my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="askus_modal" style="display:none" >  
....
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" id="askus_cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="askus_submit" type="button">Submit</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

How do I invoke an alert box(for example) upon the click of Submit button??

I tried:

```
<script>
    $("#askus_submit").live("click", function(event){
        alert( "GO" ); 
    });
</script>
```

and

```
 <script>
     $('#askus_modal').on("click","#askus_submit", function () {
        alert("GO");
  });
 </script>
```

but both are not working.. can anyone help? I am really new to this

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added this line in headers..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and try using your first script tag code..

Comment: and yes if it still doesn't work.. check javascript console of your browser as mentioned by @undefined.